# how to host asp.net app locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a ASP.NET website, developed by a freelancer. After developing the website, he directly uploaded the website to my domain. Now, how can I host that website locally on my computer?

I dont have any experience in ASP.NET, however I do know HTML5 and CSS3. Looking at the files, I noticed they are all `.cshtml` files.

Any help would be great. I have the login credentials of Plesk.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to launch a debug with visual studio this should be too easy  to do

Answer (score 3):

You need to use IIS.

To do this, assuming you are on Windows, you need to enable it under the 'Windows Features' setting screen as below:
[image]

Check the 'World Wide Web Services' option, and also 'IIS Management Console' under the 'Web Management Tools' section.

After it installs, you will have a new program in your start menu, called 'Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager'.

This is where you setup and configure any local websites. There will already be a default website set up, which you can use, or you can create a new one by right clicking on 'Sites' in the tree on the left, and selecting 'Add Website':

[image]

Assuming you just use the default, you will need to copy your application to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`. You will then be able to access this by pointing your browser to `http:\\localhost` or `http:\\127.0.0.1`.

Comment: There is no need to copy the site to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` - You can put it anywhere and let IIS know where's the website folder. wwwroot is just a default.

Comment: true, I was trying to simplify the steps.

Comment: Great content! Stack overflow needs more of this!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with Windows, you will need to install an IIS on your machine. IIS is a part of Window's features, you can try installing it under:
Control Panel > Program and features > Turn windows features On / Off > Internet Information Services.

[image]

In some versions of windows, IIS is not available. In that case, you will need to download [IISExpress](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview).

After that - Configure a new website under your IIS, and point the website to the directory in your computer which has the project.

[image]

[image]

### Read more here:

[Installing IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx)

[Setting up a website](http://www.plus2net.com/asp-tutorial/iis-localsite.php)